# Python - Noob Question - What does it mean "Giving one of the optional arguments"?

Tags: python, arguments, default-value

What does this do?
giving one of the optional arguments:
**ask_ok('OK to overwrite the file?', 2)**

```
def ask_ok(prompt, retries=4, complaint='Yes or no, please!'):
    while True:
        ok = input(prompt)
        if ok in ('y', 'ye', 'yes'):
            return True
        if ok in ('n', 'no', 'nop', 'nope'):
            return False
        retries = retries - 1
        if retries < 0:
            raise IOError('refusenik user')
        print(complaint)
```

See tutorial:
http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets `retries` to 2 and leaves `complaint` on the default value 'Yes or no, please!'. The order of the optional arguments in the first line of the function definition is important.

Answer (score 4):

In Python there are several types of arguments:

- positional and keyword
- named and arbitrary

The function argument in Python is an attribution operation, that is, arguments are assigned to variables in the function local namespace.

If you have a declaration like this:

```
def some_func(pos_arg1, pos_arg2, kw_arg1=1, kw_arg2='test'):
    print "postional arg 1 =", pos_arg1
    print "postional arg 2 =", pos_arg2
    print "keyword arg 1 =", kw_arg1
    print "keyword arg 2 =", kw_arg2
```

Positional arguments are mandatory and will be assigned in the given order, but keyword arguments are optional and can be called in any order - when omitted, named keyword arguments assume the declared default values (1 and 'test' in the example). So far:

```
>>> some_func(1) # positional arguments are mandatory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: some_func() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
>>> some_func(1, 2) # this is ok
postional arg 1 = 1
postional arg 2 = 2
keyword arg 1 = 1
keyword arg 2 = test
>>> some_func(1, 2, 3) # this is also ok, keyword args may work like positional
postional arg 1 = 1
postional arg 2 = 2
keyword arg 1 = 3
keyword arg 2 = test
>>> some_func(1, 2, 3, 4) # this is also ok, keyword args may work like positional
postional arg 1 = 1
postional arg 2 = 2
keyword arg 1 = 3
keyword arg 2 = 4
>>> some_func(1, 2, kw_arg2=3) # kyword arguments may be given in any order
postional arg 1 = 1
postional arg 2 = 2
keyword arg 1 = 1
keyword arg 2 = 3
```

There is a problem with undeclared arguments:

```
>>> some_func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: some_func() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
```

But you can have an arbitrary number of arguments in using the special form `*` and `**`:

```
>>> def some_func(pos_arg1, pos_arg2, *args, **kw_args):
...     print "postional arg 1 =", pos_arg1
...     print "postional arg 2 =", pos_arg2
...     print "other positional orgs =", args
...     print "other keyword args =", kw_args
... 
>>> some_func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) # any number of arguments
postional arg 1 = 1
postional arg 2 = 2
other positional orgs = (3, 4, 5)
other keyword args = {}
>>> some_func(1, 2, a=3, x=4, y=5) # * and ** are optional
postional arg 1 = 1
postional arg 2 = 2
other positional orgs = ()
other keyword args = {'a': 3, 'x': 4, 'y': 5}
>>> some_func(1, 2, 'banana', 'orange', 'apple', a=3, x=4, y=5)
postional arg 1 = 1
postional arg 2 = 2
other positional orgs = ('banana', 'orange', 'apple')
other keyword args = {'a': 3, 'x': 4, 'y': 5}
>>>
```

The `*` argument will be available as a tuple of positional arguments, and `**` will be a dict of keyword arguments.

You can mix everything together but there is a rule: all keyword arguments have to be declared after positional arguments, and all the arbitrary must be after named ones.

Comment: Why do you have to give a least 2 arguments?

Comment: Because named positional arguments are mandatory. You can make it optional with `def some_func(*args)`.

Comment: unless you just assign them a value.. some_func(pos_arg1=5, pos_arg2=6, kw_arg1=1, kw_arg2='test'):

Comment: If you assign them a value they are not positional arguments anymore, they turn into keyword arguments.

Comment: Ok, I need to understand all the different types of arguments, I'm up to that tonight.

Answer (score 1):

This is a function.

If you are learning python I recommend you first read a good book like "Learning python". Start with simple tutorial and read a lot. After read a lot read more and more. Python is a beatifull language to start programming. Sometimes, like me, you will thing in some others languages but stay with python and you can have good results.

Comment: Nothing is wrong in Python Tutorial. The Python Docs and tutorial are best resource in the world. 

But to learn (anything) books are better because they follow some logic. You can find in http://stackoverflow.com/ books recommended by users. 
I recommend "Learning Python". After good understading enjoy the docs! You can learn by tutorials but in my opinion books are better.